# How to set input type and format in EditText using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I want to force users to enter a Number and i'm using that (and it's working fine):

```
android:inputType="number"
```

I want to force the user to make the input just two numbers (Int or Double does not matter) and those numbers must be between 0 and 20 (or 0.0 and 20.0) :
e.g :
0 or 0.0
1 or 1.5 (1.0 etc)
.
.
.
20 or 20.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how I like to do this:

add this for edit text

```
 android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

(or)

```
android:digits="0123456789."
```

**Kotlin::**

```
class InputFilterMinMax(min:Float, max:Float): InputFilter {
    private var min:Float = 0.0F
    private var max:Float = 0.0F

    init{
        this.min = min
        this.max = max
    }

    override fun filter(source:CharSequence, start:Int, end:Int, dest: Spanned, dstart:Int, dend:Int): CharSequence? {
        try
        {
            val input = (dest.subSequence(0, dstart).toString() + source + dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length)).toFloat()
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null
        }
        catch (nfe:NumberFormatException) {}
        return ""
    }

    private fun isInRange(a:Float, b:Float, c:Float):Boolean {
        return if (b > a) c in a..b else c in b..a
    }
}
```

Then set the filter on your EditText:

```
myEditText.setFilters(arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilterMinMax(0.0F, 20.0F)))
```

**Java:**

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {
    private float min;
    private float max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(float min, float max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        //noinspection EmptyCatchBlock
        try {
            float input = Float.parseFloat(dest.subSequence(0, dstart).toString() + source + dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length()));
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(float a, float b, float c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Then set the filter on your EditText:

```
myEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax(0.0, 20.0)});
```

Comment: can you give it to me in kotlin please !

Comment: thanks, it's working correctly (it's force user to create a number just between 0 and 20 but it is always Int the user can't write e.g: 10.5 )

Comment: Ok. nice to hear that it works, check my updated answer  again and see if issue is fixed

Comment: the same problem brother only the keyboard has change

Comment: i think we must change the type of min and max to Double

Comment: Yes. agreed. I changed int to float. can u check it now

Comment: there is a problem in this line :             val input = Float.parseFloat.parseInt(dest.subSequence(0, dstart).toString() + source + dest.subSequence(

Comment: parseFloat is writing in red (" Unresolved Reference : parseFloat ")

Comment: I updated my code. use toFloat instead of Float.parseFloat() in kotlin

Comment: thank you very much it's working fine...please is there anyway to get only the numerical keyboard.

Comment: add this    android:inputType="numberDecimal"

Answer (score -2):

Use a TextWatcher

[Android Docs - TEXT WATCHER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher)