# Keyboard not displaying the correct input - Kotlin Android S

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building a wordle clone which create programmatically EditText fields within a programmatically created TableRow within a pre-made in XML TableLayout.

The EditText should open the keyboard with letters

Right now when I focus on an EditText, it's the numpad that opens

What I tried for the keyboard:

1. Trying to force the keyboard to open programatically to the "letters" instead of "numpad", but couldn't find the exact way of doing it
2. Trying to play with all the EditText options to make sure it was a "character"/"text" and there was no weird thing that would make the emulator interpreting it as a "number"
3. Trying to dig into the options of formatting for TableLayout and

The code works great (As in, the edit text appear, I can enter letters). But what is displayed for the end-user is numbers, which isn't great.

This function create a new Row every time (it's a "companion object")

```
 fun createNewRow(tableMain: TableLayout, lengthOfWord: Int, rowActive: Int,wordManager: WordManager, buttonValidate: ImageButton) {
        var newTableRow: TableRow = TableRow(tableMain.context)

        for (i in 0 until lengthOfWord) { //Setup every single EditText in there

            var newUserInputTextField = EditText(newTableRow.context)
            SetupInputText(newUserInputTextField, lengthOfWord)} // Take care of all the formatting
```

the SetupInputText() function is the following :

```
    fun SetupInputText(InputText: EditText, lengthOfWord: Int){
        InputText.setHint(R.string.fill_boxes)
        InputText.isAllCaps = true //This doesn't work for some reason
        InputText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS) //This was to try and force the app to open the normal keyboard. Doesn't work.
        InputText.textSize = pixelConverterFromDP(20f).toFloat()
        InputText.width = pixelConverterFromDP(60f*5/lengthOfWord)
        InputText.height = pixelConverterFromDP(100f)
        InputText.charactersOnly()
        InputText.setMaxLength(2)
        InputText.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    }
```

[The code as a whole is available on gitHub](https://github.com/RhevanP/DefinitelyNotWorlde)

Comment: I think your raw type needs to be `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS` as per https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:inputType - *textCapWords* needs to be comboed with the *text* type (which corresponds to the first two flags). And I think you need to call `setAllCaps(true)`, maybe you can do `allCaps = true` as well. I don't know if that will fix it, but it might!

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Regarding the InputType, that's right. Though on Kotlin I need to add a `or` instead of `|`, otherwise the code doesn't seem to work.
I just tried it and it is still opening the numpad. I think I'll try to create a `onFocusChange` event listener to get to open the specific type of keyboard I want it to open. Not great, but can't find anything else.

For the setAllCaps, I think the IDE tells me to use the allCaps (I tried both in the past, none worked). But it may be related to the first issue (like the thing detect a number input for some weird reason)

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure, sorry - your code from the question works fine for me, except for the `charactersOnly` and `setMaxLength` methods which don't exist (I just replaced them with `filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.AllCaps(), InputFilter.LengthFilter(2))` - `isAllCaps` doesn't work if the text is editable). Tapping one of the `EditText`s opens the keyboard normally with the alphabet display visible, on an API 31 emulator with the built-in keyboard. (If you want to prevent the user from *entering* numbers though, you'll need a filter for that)

Comment: Thank you for adding in those details! I played around deleting the `setMaxLength` and using the `InputFilter.LengthFilter(2)` and `InputFilter.AllCaps()` instead, working the same (but better for the readability of the code. Though I also commented out `charactersOnly()` which seemed to have resolved the keyboard issue... So there's something on the custom function that was messing up the type of Input for the keyboard! I'll dig into it. Thanks again for the help, I'll write a full answer tagging you as the main reason how I found it once I fully solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : This has been changed following the feedback from cactustictacs about not relying on converting an input to float

Thank you [cactustictacs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13598222/cactustictacs) for helping with this question and giving me most of the thinking to find all the issues.

I should have used
`InputText.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(2), InputFilter.AllCaps())`
To force all letters to be all caps and limit the input of 2

My `EditText.charactersOnly()` function was causing an issue on the input.
In there I was using `keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM”)`

I should have tried to build a custom filter instead using
[How to set input type and format in EditText using kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758285/how-to-set-input-type-and-format-in-edittext-using-kotlin) and pl.kotl.in/PmTYVzod4 (from [cactustictacs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13598222/cactustictacs))
As a reference
Which is

```
 class InputFilterTextOnly(): InputFilter {
            private val allowedChars = ('a'..'z').plus('A'..'Z').joinToString("")
            override fun filter(
                source: CharSequence,
                start: Int,
                end: Int,
                dest: Spanned,
                dstart: Int,
                dend: Int
            ): CharSequence? {
//                Log.v("FILTERCUSTOM", dest.toString())
//                Log.v("FILTERCUSTOM", source.toString())
                return source.filter { it in allowedChars }
            }
        }
```

(Uncomment the Log.v() to understand how the thing works)

Keep in mind that I use the `source` directly because my input is limited to 1, I have a TextWatcher in the code limiting it.

With the filter being :
`InputText.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(2), InputFilterTextOnly(),InputFilter.AllCaps())`

So first the filter will make sure it never goes above 2, then it’ll make sure it’s text only and caps it up.

Comment: Yeah `DigitsKeyListener` is for digits-only input - it's only meant for hardware keyboards anyway (always check the docs!) and software keyboards can react to it however they want. At a guess, whatever keyboard you're using takes it as a hint that the input is digits-only, and shows the numpad keyboard

Comment: But just checking - are you using your filter to check if the input can be parsed as a Float, and if not you're accepting it? You're gonna run into a lot of bugs doing that - as well as the edge cases around `InputFilter`'s handling of editing the middle of the text and pasting stuff in, just typing into your box will allow things like `A2` and non-alphabetical content like punctuation. Try something like this instead: https://pl.kotl.in/PmTYVzod4

Comment: Again, thank you very much for this. I think I would have the issue with `A2` type of input because I have a TextWatcher making sure the string is composed of 1 character. Though you definitely showed an issue with the code, your `filter{it in allowedChar}` is definitely better. I'll update my post!